# Prove that this reasoning with $4$ propositions is valid or invalid

Tags: logic

> Is the following reasoning valid or invalid?: $$\begin{array}{l}p\to q\vee r\\p\vee(\neg t\vee s)\\\neg q\wedge\neg s\\s\to\neg t\\\hline\therefore\neg t\end{array}$$

---

Let's use the associated conditional method. Let's find the associated conditional of the reasoning: $$[(p\to q\vee r)\wedge(p\vee(\neg t\vee s))\wedge(\neg q\wedge\neg s)\wedge(s\to\neg t)]\to\neg t$$ Suppose that $\mathrm{T}\to\mathrm{F}\equiv\mathrm{F}$ i.e.: $$\begin{array}{}&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\\\\
\implies&[&(&p&\to&q&\vee&r&)&\wedge&(&p&\vee&(&\neg&t&\vee&s&)&)&\wedge&(&\neg&q&\wedge&\neg&s&)&\wedge&(&s&\to&\neg&t&)&]&\to&\neg&t&\\&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{V}&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}\end{array}$$ Since we can fill all the holes **without any contradiction** we conclude that **the reasoning is invalid**, because we assumed that $\mathrm{T}\to\mathrm{F}$ and ended up with something that is not contradictory.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it is very very hard to read because of the formatting. I made the whole method much more clear in my Answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is too wide to read on the site and it's not clear what your reasoning with it is. (The $\Rightarrow$s on the left are especially perplexing).

It looks like you're intending the table to document that you're following a particular heuristic for searching for a truth assignment that shows the reasoning to be invalid. And it is all well and good if that method *works for you*, but showing the entire table is superfluous if all you're after is a **proof that the reasoning is invalid**. To do that, all you need to show is the *final truth assignment* that makes all of the premises true and the conclusion false:

$$ \begin{array}{c|c} p & q & r & s & t \\ \hline T & F& T& F& T \end{array} $$
You can then, if you think more detail is needed, show that this truth assignment does lead to each of the premises being true, and the conclusion being false.

But you don't need to narrate step-by-step how you *found* this proof. (Unless, that is, if you're in a classroom situation where the exercise explicitly asks you to apply such-and-such method and show the steps).

Comment: Thanks! So as long as you found certain values that make the premises true but the conclusion false, then the reasoning is invalid, right?

Comment: @manooooh: Correct.

Comment: I am not agree with "But you don't need to narrate step-by-step how you *found* this proof". Suppose that my method is correct but I have made a mistake in the calculations. Then how would you help me to find out *where* is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You did that exactly right!

Unfortunately, because of the formatting you used, it's almost impossible to read. To solve the formatting problem, I decided to not create the whole conditional for the argument, but to simply leave the premises and conclusion by themselves, and indicate the truth-value assignment whose possibility I am interested in, i,e.:

\begin{array}{}
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}\\\\
\end{array}

Actually, when I use this method, I always use this set-up: creating a conditional for the argument as a whole, and then going through the first few steps gets you exactly to this point, and so working with the whole conditional is just a waste of time.

Now, I *do* recommend adding a few more steps in between, so you can really see the order in which you assign those truth-values. Your steps are sometimes a little hard to follow. Below is what I mean. I use red color to indicate the newly forced truth-values, and blue to indicate from which existing truth-values they are forced:

\begin{array}{rrrrlrrrrrlrlrrrrrrrl}
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&\mathrm{F}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&&\mathrm{T}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&&\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&&&&\mathrm{T}&&&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&&&\mathrm{T}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&&\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&&&&&\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&&&&&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&&&&&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\color{red}{\mathrm{F}}&&&&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&{\mathrm{T}}\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}&{\mathrm{F}}&\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&&&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&{\mathrm{T}}{\mathrm{F}}&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
p&\to&(q & \vee & r)&,&p&\vee&(\neg t & \vee & s)&, & \neg q & \wedge & \neg s &, & s & \to & \neg t & \therefore & \neg t\\
{\mathrm{T}}&{\mathrm{T}}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{F}}&\color{blue}{\mathrm{T}}&\color{red}{\mathrm{T}}&&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&{\mathrm{F}}&\mathrm{F}&&{\mathrm{T}}{\mathrm{F}}&{\mathrm{T}}&\mathrm{T}\mathrm{F}&&\mathrm{F}&\mathrm{T}&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}&&\mathrm{F}\mathrm{T}\\\\
\end{array}